# New SSL certificate to be in place by 1st October

Tags: facebook, ssl, facebook-apps

I have been reading the developer blog on Facebook this morning and stumbled across this [article](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/oauth2-https-migration/) saying that *all* Canvas pages are to use OAuth and SSL.

> • an SSL Certificate is required for all Canvas and Page Tab apps (not
>   in Sandbox mode)
>
> • old, previous versions of our SDKs will stop working, including the
>   old JavaScript SDK, old iOS SDK

Does this really mean that any application that has been created before this date will stop working?  Am I really going to have to buy an SSL certificate for each application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes looks like it. They told [developers on 11th May 2011](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/497/) :

> Today, we are announcing an update to our Developer Roadmap that
>   outlines a plan requiring all sites and apps to migrate to OAuth 2.0,
>   process the signed_request parameter, and obtain an SSL certificate by
>   October 1.
>
> **Migration to OAuth 2.0 + HTTPS timeline**:
>
> - **July 1**: Updates to the PHP and JS SDKs available that use OAuth 2.0
>     and have new cookie format (without access token). September 1: All
>     apps must migrate to OAuth 2.0 and expect an encrypted access token.
> - **October 1**: **All Canvas apps must process signed_request (fb_sig will be
>     removed) and obtain an SSL certificate** (unless you are in Sandbox
>     mode). This will ensure that users browsing Facebook over HTTPS will
>     have a great experience over a secure connection. We believe these
>     changes create better and more secure experiences for users of your
>     app. A migration plan below outlines the potential impact on your
>     apps.

From [here](http://www.sourcecoast.com/jfbconnect/docs/common-support-questions/ssl-certificates-for-facebook):

> Please Note: An SSL certificate is not required for user
>   authentication on your site, Likes, Comments or other things. It's
>   only used if you want to show your site (or parts of it) inside the
>   Facebook.com domain.
>
> Once your SSL certificate is installed on your site, you'll simply
>   need to enter your new secure URL into the "Secure Canvas URL" and
>   "Secure Tab URL". To obtain and install an SSL Certificate, we've
>   partnered with The SSL Store in order to make the process as smooth as
>   possible. SSL Certificates that work with Facebook can be purchased
>   for as little as $11/year (multi-year) or $18 for just one year.
>
> Purchasing a certificate through The SSL Store takes about 10 minutes
>   and they have a 30-day money back guarantee.
>
> Below are instructions on how to purchase a new SSL certificate for
>   your site so that you can use the Facebook Page features without any
>   issue.

It does seem that you need to have one, and not one per app.

Comment: This is good information, but will I need multiple SSL certificates (per client) or will 1 be sufficient?  This is the information that I've not been able to find.

Comment: I think that would be good question for facebook to answer. Personally I doubt you will.