# facebook application giving error when using https url

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created application in iframe Facebook. 
When i access [apps.facebook.com/samkhkhkh/](http://apps.facebook.com/samkhkhkh/) itz working but when i access https://apps.facebook.com/samkhkhkh/ giving this error

> This webpage is not available.
>    The webpage at https://bluesoften.com/sample/?fb_source=bookmark_apps&ref=bookmarks&count=0&fb_bmpos=3_0
>   might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
>   Error 501 (net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE): Unknown error.

Comment: do you have a SSL certificate for your domain?

Comment: you must use a valid SSL certificate to use facebooks applications -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/7360609/1507900

Comment: This is what I get in Chrome: `The site's security certificate is not trusted!`. Check your certificate.

Comment: no i dont have but how can i fixed this ssl certificate

Comment: Syed, you'll need to **buy it** from someplace like [Thawte](https://www.thawte.com).